# passing this.method in setTimeout doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I am seeing problem with passing object method as argument to setTimeout.
I know inside nested function, scope of this need to be set manually but what if i directly pass function object, in my case this.counting. What is the need of declaring anonymous function as first argument, this.counting is already a function.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) also uses function(msg) {self.remind(msg);} instead of this.remind inside setTimeout first argument.

```
function Timer(count,start){
    this.count = count;
    this.start = start;

}

//below code works
Timer.prototype.counting = function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){self.counting();},this.start);
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count++;
};

//below code doesn't work
/*
Timer.prototype.counting = function(){
    setTimeout(this.counting,this.start);
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count++;
};
*/
var t1 = new Timer(0,1000);
t1.counting();
var t2 = new Timer(100,1000);
t2.counting();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The MDN documentation of `setTimeout` has a whole section about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem), I recommend to read it.

---

Inside the callback you pass to `setTimeout`, `this` will refer to `window`, not to the instance of your class.

If the function is called, `this.count` (which refers to `window.count`) would be `undefined`, since there is no global `count` variable. Later it would become `NaN` (`undefined++` is `NaN`). The `count` property of your object would not change at all.

By calling the function explicitly as a method of the object (`self.counting()`), you ensure that `this` correctly refers to the instance of your class.

You could achieve the same by using [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), instead of using another function:

```
setTimeout(this.counting.bind(this), this.start);
```

Read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn more about `this`.